# Putting a value from a method into a property array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

```
const cart = {
  contents: [],
  addItem() {

  }
};
cart.addItem("laptop");
console.log("The cart contains:", cart.contents);
```

how would I put the items in the addItem method into the content property array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `push`:

```js
const cart = {
  contents: [],
  addItem(item) {
    this.contents.push(item);
  }
};
cart.addItem("laptop");
console.log("The cart contains:", cart.contents);
```

If you want to pass multiple items like `addItem("laptop", "phone")`, use spreading:

```js
const cart = {
  contents: [],
  addItem(...items) {
    this.contents.push(...items);
  }
};
cart.addItem("laptop", "phone");
console.log("The cart contains:", cart.contents);
```

Comment: Thank you!, never thought I would get an answer this quick

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this `this.contents.push(item)`

```js
const cart = {
  contents: [],
  addItem(item) {
     this.contents.push(item)
  }
};
cart.addItem("laptop");
console.log("The cart contains:", cart.contents);
```